# Notepad++ to automatically monitor a log file, editing the last line then saving the last line to new file

Tags: notepad++

Please excuse my total newby status but I was wondering if anybody could help me out here.

I have a log file of music artist and titles that gets updated every time a new song plays. I want to automate editing each new line as it is generated and save that line to a new text file or ultimately send the contents of that last line via TCP/IP as if sent by a terminal program.

I have figured out how to monitor the log and move to the last line using the "file status detection" feature in Notepadd++ and I have figured out to edit the line using find and replace. I am not sure how to proceed to take that last line and save it to a new file. Or preferably send the edited last line via TCP/IP.

Is this possible using notepad++?

Here is a sample of the log prior to editing it:

```
12-May-2013 03:14:31 Twisted: Disco vs Ots Labs - The Way You Move [Beat Mix]
12-May-2013 03:15:34 Digital 03 vs Ots Labs - Busy Body [Radio Edit]
12-May-2013 03:16:38 Digital 03 vs Ots Labs - Busy Body [Beat Mix]
12-May-2013 03:18:50 In-Yo-Face vs Ots Labs - I Really Love You Girl [Beat Mix]
```

After editing:

```
DPS=Twisted: Disco vs Ots Labs ; The Way You Move [Beat Mix]
DPS=Digital 03 vs Ots Labs ; Busy Body [Radio Edit]
DPS=Digital 03 vs Ots Labs ; Busy Body [Beat Mix]
DPS=In;Yo;Face vs Ots Labs ; I Really Love You Girl [Beat Mix]
```

Like I said, I am a total newby and am planning on using a macro that does the editing. I want to run the macro each time the log is updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

This cannot by achieved by changes in configuration. This can be possible done via scripting in N++ or by scripting or programming outside the N++. So if you create your own independent tool for this, you even may not need N++ at all.